# Irrational equation with 2 terms

Tags: irrational-numbers

Let $ n \in \mathbb{N}, n \ge 2$.

Prove that

$\sqrt[n] {\sqrt{2018}+\sqrt{2017}}$ $+$ $\sqrt[n]{\sqrt{2018}-\sqrt{2017}} $ $\in \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Q}$

Any ideas? I noticed that first member multiply with the second is equal with $1$. I tried to use Viette relations, but i can't finish the solution. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Do you mean $\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: @almagest yes, i’m sorry. I’m begginer with Latex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is enough to prove the following statement:  If $a+b \in \mathbb Q$ with $ab=1$, then $f(n)=a^n+b^n \in \mathbb Q$, for $n \in \mathbb N$.

Let us use induction. The statement is trivial for $n=1$.

Suppose it holds true for all $n\leqslant m$.  Then, from 
$$(a+b)^{m+1}=f(m+1)+\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor m/2\rfloor}\binom{m+1}k f(m+1-2k)$$
it follows that $f(m+1)$ must also be rational, hence we have our proof by strong induction.

Comment: Thank you so much. I apreciate your effort

Answer (score 0):

Let $a=\sqrt{2018}+\sqrt{2017}$ and $b =\sqrt{2018}-\sqrt{2017}$.  As you noticed, $ab=1$ and $a+b=2\sqrt{2018} \not \in \mathbb Q$.

Suppose $u=a^{1/n} + b^{1/n} \in \mathbb Q$.  Then we have $v = a^{1/n}\cdot b^{1/n}=1\in \mathbb Q$ also.  As symmetric polynomials can be always expressed in terms of elementary symmetric polynomials with rational coefficients, $a+b$ must be expressible in terms of $u, v$, so $a+b$ must also be rational.  Hence, there is a contradiction.

Comment: Do you know another solution? Without polynomials? I didn't  studied them at school.

Comment: @RaduAndrei It may help to clarify what you are familiar with - will see if there is a simpler way, perhaps with induction which I assume you know.

Comment: Yes, i know induction. I hope there is a way to solve this with induction

Comment: OK. Have put up an answer with induction, and it is simpler...